# what does movl $1, %ebx mean?

Tags: assembly

movl destinationaddress , source address is the usual convention . But movl  $1, %ebx isnt meaningful because $1 is not an address  location .

Intel Processor .

Comment: You're thinking in Intel syntax. This is AT&T syntax, where `instruction src, dst` is the usual form. See [GCC Assembly syntax](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3) for more info on AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed meaningful, you just don't know this syntax (it's called the AT&T style).

What it does is loading the value `1` into the `EBX` register.

Comment: Sorry.Had both the AT&T and Intel assembly codes side by side .